# Writing a text on the top of the data in a dat file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, fwrite

I want to create a data file similar like this:

[image]

I developed a script file to do this like that:

```
fid = fopen('output.dat','w');
writetext = 'zone i=401, j=961';
fwrite(fid,writetext);
dlmwrite('output.dat',sort2,'delimiter','\t','precision','%.8f');
fclose(fid);
```

However, when I run this code, the text part of the file, "zone i=401, j=961" disappears as seen in the image below:

[image]

How can I keep the text part of the data file on the top of my file?

Comment: I don't have MATLAB at the moment to test, does calling `fopen` with the `a` flag instead of the `w` flag fix this?

Comment: Hey thanks but I have changed "w" with "a" and it did not work

Comment: How about leaving `fopen` with the `w` flag and specifying the `'-append'` flag in `dlmwrite` (from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html))?

Comment: Thanks, this works but now the appended data is not started from a newline. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) by default overwrites the whole file. Use `'-append'` option to avoid that (as noted by @excaza in comments).
- You need a new line character after the title. For that, use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) and add `n` or `\r\n` after your title. `\n` is used in general to start new line, but `\r\n` may be needed in Windows.

With these changes, the code is as follows. Changed lines are third and fourth.

```
fid = fopen('output.dat','w');
writetext = 'zone i=401, j=961';
fprintf(fid, '%s\r\n', writetext);
dlmwrite('output.dat',sort2,'-append','delimiter','\t','precision','%.8f');
fclose(fid);
```